# what if the list contains values like interger numbers in list like list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',5,4,433,"fdff",44,2323] contains values like 5,4,433

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

what if the list contains values like integer numbers in list like

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',5,4,433,"fdff",44,2323]
```

contains values like 5,4,433, so how to filter them using list comprehensive in python?

Python List Comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `[i for i in list1 if type(i) == int]` to select out the integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
list1=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',5,4,433,"fdff",44,2323] 

list2=[a for a in list1 if isinstance(a, int)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `filter` with `isinstance`:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), list_1)))
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to use the same name for both the input list and the lambda parameter that each item of the list feeds into. The OP asks for a list comprehension, which is also generally considered the Pythonic approach compared to a filter with a lambda function.

Comment: @blhsing Edited my answer... It was a typo while I was posting

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
[i for i in list1 if type(i) is int]
```

Or

```
[i for i in list1 if str(i).isnumeric()]
```